# Reshaping a dataframe with a huge character column into several numeric columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape2

I have a dataset with a complex column `results` as (`character` class).

Data sample is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UKLP2ueIWudFDx_3Dqo0CNygLvie8AV0XxLmVHx94jE/edit?usp=sharing).

```
date_agenda id_question id_event results
2020-09-04  202009043   7426      "2:1:3|3:1:3|4:8:4|5:1:4|6:7:0|7:7:4|8:7:3|9:3:0|10:8:4|11:1:0|12:8:4|13:8:4|14:8:1|15:1:3|16:1:0|17:1:3|18:1:3|"
2020-09-04  202009044   7427      "2:1:3|3:1:3|4:8:4|5:1:4|6:7:0|7:7:4|8:7:3|9:3:0|10:8:4|11:1:0|12:8:4|13:8:4|14:8:3|15:1:3|16:1:0|17:1:3|18:1:3|"
2020-09-04  202009046   7428      "2:1:1|3:1:1|4:8:4|5:1:4|6:7:0|7:7:4|8:7:1|9:3:0|10:8:4|11:1:0|12:8:4|13:8:4|14:8:3|15:1:1|16:1:0|17:1:1|18:1:1|"
```

I would like to convert `results` and the whole dataframe from **wide to long format**, splitting the last column `results` into three numeric columns.

For example, `2:1:3` is one event in `results` and there hundreds of such events in this column.

My desired output:

```
date_agenda id_question id_event mp_id mp_fraction result
2020-09-04  202009043   7426       2         1        3
2020-09-04  202009043   7426       3         1        3
2020-09-04  202009043   7426       4         8        4
2020-09-04  202009043   7426       5         1        4
2020-09-04  202009043   7426       6         7        0
```

Basically, one row in the initial wide format (4 columns) will be converted into hundreds of rows in the long format (6 columns).

I understand that it should be done with `pivot_longer`, `pivot_wider` (or `gather` and `spread`) and maybe `melt`, but not sure that I have the logic now. **Whether I should split the character first into hundreds of columns and then make it wide or something else.**

Appreciate tips! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your input data in reproducible form.

Comment: Ehm, that's not exactly what is meant here by reproducible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @sindri_baldur, I got the answer, thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` to split `results` on `"|"` into different rows and `separate` to split on `":"` in three different columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(results, sep = '\\|') %>%
  #To remove empty values generated from last "|"
  filter(results != '') %>%
  separate(results,c("mp_id", "mp_fraction", "result"), sep = ":",convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 51 x 6
#   date_agenda id_question id_event mp_id mp_fraction result
#   <chr>             <int>    <int> <int>       <int>  <int>
# 1 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     2           1      3
# 2 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     3           1      3
# 3 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     4           8      4
# 4 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     5           1      4
# 5 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     6           7      0
# 6 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     7           7      4
# 7 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     8           7      3
# 8 2020-09-04    202009043     7426     9           3      0
# 9 2020-09-04    202009043     7426    10           8      4
#10 2020-09-04    202009043     7426    11           1      0
# … with 41 more rows
```

Comment: Perfect solution, Ronak Shan!

Answer (score 1):

and the obligatory `data.table` solution ;-)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table::fread('date_agenda id_question id_event results
2020-09-04  202009043   7426      "2:1:3|3:1:3|4:8:4|5:1:4|6:7:0|7:7:4|8:7:3|9:3:0|10:8:4|11:1:0|12:8:4|13:8:4|14:8:1|15:1:3|16:1:0|17:1:3|18:1:3|"
2020-09-04  202009044   7427      "2:1:3|3:1:3|4:8:4|5:1:4|6:7:0|7:7:4|8:7:3|9:3:0|10:8:4|11:1:0|12:8:4|13:8:4|14:8:3|15:1:3|16:1:0|17:1:3|18:1:3|"
2020-09-04  202009046   7428      "2:1:1|3:1:1|4:8:4|5:1:4|6:7:0|7:7:4|8:7:1|9:3:0|10:8:4|11:1:0|12:8:4|13:8:4|14:8:3|15:1:1|16:1:0|17:1:1|18:1:1|"')

#first, split on pipe
ans <- DT[, list(V2 = unlist(strsplit(results, "[|]", perl = TRUE))), 
   by=.(date_agenda, id_question, id_event) ]
#the split on colon and drop the temp column
ans[, c("mp_id", "mp_fraction", "result") := tstrsplit( V2, ":") ][, -"V2" ]
```

**output**

```
#     date_agenda id_question id_event mp_id mp_fraction result
#  1:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     2           1      3
#  2:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     3           1      3
#  3:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     4           8      4
#  4:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     5           1      4
#  5:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     6           7      0
#  6:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     7           7      4
#  7:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     8           7      3
#  8:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426     9           3      0
#  9:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    10           8      4
# 10:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    11           1      0
# 11:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    12           8      4
# 12:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    13           8      4
# 13:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    14           8      1
# 14:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    15           1      3
# 15:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    16           1      0
# 16:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    17           1      3
# 17:  2020-09-04   202009043     7426    18           1      3
# 18:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     2           1      3
# 19:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     3           1      3
# 20:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     4           8      4
# 21:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     5           1      4
# 22:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     6           7      0
# 23:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     7           7      4
# 24:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     8           7      3
# 25:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427     9           3      0
# 26:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    10           8      4
# 27:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    11           1      0
# 28:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    12           8      4
# 29:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    13           8      4
# 30:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    14           8      3
# 31:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    15           1      3
# 32:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    16           1      0
# 33:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    17           1      3
# 34:  2020-09-04   202009044     7427    18           1      3
# 35:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     2           1      1
# 36:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     3           1      1
# 37:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     4           8      4
# 38:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     5           1      4
# 39:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     6           7      0
# 40:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     7           7      4
# 41:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     8           7      1
# 42:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428     9           3      0
# 43:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    10           8      4
# 44:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    11           1      0
# 45:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    12           8      4
# 46:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    13           8      4
# 47:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    14           8      3
# 48:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    15           1      1
# 49:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    16           1      0
# 50:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    17           1      1
# 51:  2020-09-04   202009046     7428    18           1      1
#     date_agenda id_question id_event mp_id mp_fraction result
```

Comment: Thank you! Never use it, but will be helpful for the community!